# Product of Two Dict Values while retaining Dict Key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have a dictionary of an unknown amount of keys, and I'm trying to get the products of all the keys combined, while still retaining which list the items came from. For example

```
dicts = {
    "d1": ["d1_value", "d1_value2"],
    "d2": ["d2_value", "d2_value2"]
}
```

I am trying to get the product of the two lists, but their origin key retained.

```
result = [
    {
        "d1": "d1_value",
        "d2": "d2_value" 
    },
    {
        "d1": "d1_value",
        "d2": "d2_value2"
    },
    {
        "d1": "d1_value2",
        "d2": "d2_value"
    },
    {
        "d1": "d1_value2",
        "d2": "d2_value2"

    }
]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can use `itertools.product` with a nested comprehension:

```
[{k: v for k, v in zip(dicts.keys(), p)} for p in product(*dicts.values())]
```

This works because the `keys` and `values` iterators of a dictionary are guaranteed to be in the same order, regardless of the ordering of the dictionary. That means that the elements of the tuple `p` will be in value order, which is the same order as the keys. The output will contain all of the outputs, but in python versions before 3.6, the output may be "shuffled", depending on the arbitrary ordering of the dictionary keys.

An alternative phrasing is

```
[dict(zip(dicts, p)) for p in product(*dicts.values())]
```

Comment: You are an absolute hero - spot on. Thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist , congratulations!